# How to get Hadamard matrices of non-$2^n$ order?

Tags: matrix

The function `HadamardMatrix` requires the argument to be of the form $2^n$. But Hadamard matrices are known for other orders as well, for instance, for order $12$. Is there a way to construct them in Mathematica?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Wolframs book "A new kind of science" p. 1073 you find for all matrices with n=4 k and n = p+1 , where p is prime, simultaneously:

```
PadLeft[Array[JacobiSymbol[#2 - #1, n - 1] &, {n, n} - 1] - 
  IdentityMatrix[n - 1], {n, n}, 1]
```

With this e.g.:

```
n = 12;
PadLeft[Array[JacobiSymbol[#2 - #1, n - 1] &, {n, n} - 1] - 
   IdentityMatrix[n - 1], {n, n}, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm for some reason it does not work for me in this code: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4558802/2513

Comment: For instance, at n=4 the diagonal of the result should 5/2 but using your formula it is 10. With `HadamardMatrix` function all works well.

Comment: Well, sorted it out, should divide by $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Are there Hadamard matrices of non-multiple-of-4 order?

Comment: @Anixx: See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) for info.

Comment: @user64494 i could not find this info in the wiki

Comment: @Anixx: As is written in the Properties section of the linked Wiki article, "The order of a Hadamard matrix must be 1, 2, or a multiple of 4".

Comment: @user64494 the code above works for n=3 as well...

Comment: @Anixx: But the one does not produce a Hadamard matrix: `n = 3;
a = PadLeft[   Array[JacobiSymbol[#2 - #1, n - 1] &, {n, n} - 1] - 
    IdentityMatrix[n - 1], {n, n}, 1];a . Transpose[a]` results in `{{3, 1, 1}, {1, 3, -1}, {1, -1, 3}}`, not in `3*IdenrityMatrix[3]`.

Comment: @user64494 what about n=668?

Comment: @Anixx: The code `n = 668; a = 
 PadLeft[Array[JacobiSymbol[#2 - #1, n - 1] &, {n, n} - 1] - 
   IdentityMatrix[n - 1], {n, n}, 1];` does not result in a Hadamard matrix because `a . Transpose[a]!=668*IdentityMatrix[668]` in version 13.1 on Windows 10. However, you accepted the answer.

Comment: Daniel Huber incorrectly quoted (see [p. 1073](https://www.wolframscience.com/nks/notes-10-6--hadamard-matrices/)). The formula works if $n=4k$ and $n=p+1$ with prime $p$ , but 667 is not prime.